# Constraint to standard Accessory View

Tags: ios, swift3

I have have a simple TableView cell with

[image]

```
cell.accessoryType = .detailButton
```

I need to add label with constraints from left side to accessoryView. I try this one code:

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-[v0]-5-[v1]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), 
    metrics: nil, views: ["v0":partTitle, "v1":self.accessoryView!]))
```

But got error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

May someone can help, how to create constraint for label from left side of cell to accessoryView

Comment: I suspect that cell.accessoryView only returns a view if you have supplied a custom one.  If I break in the debugger after setting `cell.accessoryType = .detailButton`, I find that `cell.accessoryView` is nil while the private member `cell._accessoryView` has a button as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you first set the accessoryView into an empty UIView, second you need to declare a dictionary which contains the label and the accessoryView, then you need to set the `NSLayoutFormatOptions` to 0 and remove the "H:" from the visual format. For example you can do this:

```
self.accesoryView = UIView()

let views: [String : Any] = [
    "v0" : partTitle,
    "v1" : self.accesoryView!
]
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints( withVisualFormat: "|-[v0]-5-[v1]", 
               options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),  
               metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Is important that accessoryView could not be nil.

Comment: A got error message: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

Comment: Sorry... change `"v1" : self.` to `"v1" : self.accesoryView!`. Maybe it'll solve the problem. Did you add this?

Comment: Yes, I tried using this fix. I have another I will post it later.

Comment: But, have you get teh same exception?